# Working with Google Sheets links in cells that do not have a Hyperlink formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have cells with a link and when I click right on it I see that

[image]

When I click Unlink, Convert to link option will appear. If I click it again the previous link will appear again.

[image]

I think it get link from Google Search. Is that option deprecated for other cells?

Here's link of the spreadsheet.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J8aSh3A3Rq24ku9X2ljf_8wgGq8zKw1PUmzH10i76Vc/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a link is created when rich text is pasted in a spreadsheet. For example, copy the title of your question and paste it in a Google spreadsheet.  Such links cannot be created by spreadsheet formulas or by Apps Script.

This is not a deprecated functionality. But, since you tagged this with Apps Script, I should say that a Script at present cannot access the URL that was entered in this way; they will see the cell as containing plain text. Neither can spreadsheet formulas. So if in the future you will want to extract those URLs for some use, that will be a problem. For this reason, I would discourage the use of such links.

Related: [Extract the link text and URL from a hyperlinked cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/89557), in particular [this comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89557/extract-the-link-text-and-url-from-a-hyperlinked-cell#comment85786_89557).

Comment: how to get link of that cell ?

Comment: That cannot be done by a formula or a script. Via the interface, hover over the cell, then right-click the link when it shows up, and select "copy".